# How to select a table which contains certain keyword - c# - xpath - htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, select, xpath, html-agility-pack, keyword

I have to gather information from a product page which does not have any class or id. I am using htmlagilitypack and c# 4.0.

There are many tables at this product page source code. The prices table contains " KDV" string. So i would like to get this " KDV" string containing table. How can i do that ?

The xpath below would select all tables for example

```
string srxPathOfCategory = "//table";
var selectedNodes = myDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(srxPathOfCategory);
```

The code below selects the table but starting from most outer table. I need to select most inner table which contains that given string

```
//table[contains(., ' KDV')]
```

c# , xpath , htmlagilitypack

Comment: nope. i need select the table which contains certain string via using htmlagilitypack. htmlagilitypack uses xpath.

Comment: KDV = TAX in my language . so it is a specific word for prices :) used as 45 TL + KDV  . you can not believe how bad html structure they are using yet they are top 10 online seller in Turkey.  example page : http://www.pratikev.com/fractalv33/pratikEv/pages/viewProduct.jsp?pInstanceId=3138821

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6128/discussion-between-pencho-ilchev-and-monstermmorpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code below selects the table but starting from most outer table. I
>   need to select most inner table which contains that given string

**Use**:

```
//table
    [not(descendant::table) 
   and 
     .//text()[contains(., ' KDV')]
    ]
```

This selects any `table` in the XML document that doesn't have a `table` descendant, and that has a text node descendant that contains the string `" KDV"` .

In general the above expression could select many such `table` elements.

**If you want only one of them selected (say the first), use this XPath expression -- do notice the brackets**:

```
   (//table
        [not(descendant::table) 
       and 
         .//text()[contains(., ' KDV')]
        ]
    )[1]
```

**Remember**: If you want to select the first `someName` element in the document, using this (as in the currently accepted answer) is wrong:

```
//someName[1]
```

This is the second most FAQ in XPath (after the one how to select elements with unprefixed names in an XML document with a default namespace).

The expression above actually selects any `someName` element in the document, that is the first child of its parent -- try it.

The reason for this unintuitive behavior is because the XPath `[]` operator has a higher precedence (priority) that the `//` pseudo-operator.

The correct expression that really selects only the first `someName` element (in any XML document), if such exists is:

```
(//someName)[1]
```

Here the brackets are used to explicitly override the default XPath operator precedence.

Comment: I have to say that you are the best :) so this experession is selecting that table. For selecting its TDs as nodes what do i do ? thank you : http://pastebin.com/2hHxUHa8

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: You are welcome. For selecting td s of the table, just add /td at the end: `(//table [not(descendant::table) and .//text()[contains(., ' KDV')] ] )[1]/descendant::td[1]` selects the 1st `td` of this table.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more efficient way to do it. Anyway,
this is the entire code I have used for your case and it works for me:

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        string url = "http://www.pratikev.com/fractalv33/pratikEv/pages/viewProduct.jsp?pInstanceId=3138821";
        using (var response = (WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse()))
        {
            doc.LoadHtml(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
        }
        /*There is an bug in the xpath used here. Should have been 
          (//table/tr/td/font[contains(.,'KDV')])[1]/ancestor::table[2] 
          See Dimitre's answer for an explanation and an alternative / 
          more generic / (needless to say) better approach */
        string xpath = "//table/tr/td/font[contains(.,'KDV')][1]/ancestor::table[2]"; 
        HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

Comment: this select the tables but it starts selecting from most outer . i need to select most inner table which means the first parent of KDV containing table : //table[contains(., ' KDV')]

Comment: very interesting.  These 2 codes behaves totally different because at my document get method your xpath returns null : http://pastebin.com/S9fvyMcL

Comment: strange, HtmlWeb seems to be causing the trouble. Oh, well, at least there is a way to make it working :) btw, I have changed the xpath. I think that its more efficient now.

Comment: Pencho, there are some issues with this answer -- I have provided some insight in mine.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, thanks. I knew you might come around, thus made sure I start my answer with a disclaimer :)

Comment: @PenchoIlchev: No problem, we all are lucky when we learn something new.